# Achieve 6 rows on wide browser then 2 columns, 3 rows when in mobile width using Flexbox

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I created a fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/mh4moyzy/ and I'm not sure what I need to add so that when width of browser is greater than the width of mobile which is 400px, make all of those boxes stack in rows and as wide as the browser width. That means there will be 6 rows and 1 column. In mobile, there will be 3 rows and 2 columns.

```css
 .flex-container {
      padding: 0;
      margin: 0;
      list-style: none;
      display: -webkit-box;
      display: -moz-box;
      display: -ms-flexbox;
      display: -webkit-flex;
      display: flex;
      -webkit-flex-flow: row wrap;
      justify-content: space-around;
    }
    .flex-item {
      background: tomato;
      padding: 5px;
      width: 200px;
      height: 150px;
      margin-top: 10px;
      line-height: 150px;
      color: white;
      font-weight: bold;
      font-size: 3em;
      text-align: center;
  }
```

```html
    <ul class="flex-container">
      <li class="flex-item">1</li>
      <li class="flex-item">2</li>
      <li class="flex-item">3</li>
      <li class="flex-item">4</li>
      <li class="flex-item">5</li>
      <li class="flex-item">6</li>
    </ul>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use media query for that. For making flex items take all width and have column direction add this code

```
@media (min-width: 400px) {
  .flex-container {
    flex-direction: column;
  }

  .flex-item {
    width: auto;
  }
}
```

Also if you want to always have 2 columns in your mobile you can add this styles to `.flex-item`:

```
width: calc(50% - 10px);
box-sizing: border-box;
```

So example will look like:

```css
.flex-container {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    list-style: none;
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -moz-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-flex-flow: row wrap;
    justify-content: space-around;
}
.flex-item {
    background: tomato;
    padding: 5px;
    width: calc(50% - 10px); /* replacing fixed width with percentage */
    height: 150px;
    margin-top: 10px;
    line-height: 150px;
    color: white;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 3em;
    text-align: center;
    box-sizing: border-box; /* Setting borders and paddings to be considered part of width */
}

@media (min-width: 400px) {
  .flex-container {
    flex-direction: column;
  }
  
  .flex-item {
    width: auto;
  }
}
```

```html
<ul class="flex-container">
    <li class="flex-item">1</li>
    <li class="flex-item">2</li>
    <li class="flex-item">3</li>
    <li class="flex-item">4</li>
    <li class="flex-item">5</li>
    <li class="flex-item">6</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Your solution kind of works but when I resized my browser to less than 400px, it's not doing the 2 column squares anymore. https://jsfiddle.net/mh4moyzy/1/

Comment: @devwannabe You have fixed width for flex items of `200px`. So I'll be surprised if there will be 2 columns. Consider using smaller value or not using fixed width.

Comment: Got it. I think I got it working but not sure if my solution is the recommended. Check it out - https://jsfiddle.net/mh4moyzy/2/

Comment: Actually, your code worked in jsfiddle but not the one inside stackoverflow even if I clicked fullpage. Check this out - https://jsfiddle.net/mh4moyzy/3/

Comment: @devwannabe StackOverflow snippets don't have resize feature so you won't see mobile layout here. By the way please use `border-box` for more maintainable solution https://jsfiddle.net/mh4moyzy/5/ I hope I solved your problem.